# httpx.ReadTimeout on Range filter on Supabase-py

Tags: python, supabase-py

I have 375000 items in my table.
I am doing a loop to obtain all id of all items, with API limit set to 20000 items per api call.
After 200000 I always start to get httpx.ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out sometime it may reach 240000 but never go ahead.

I have tried to have different wait time after each loop.
I have tried to change api limit to 10000 as well as increase it to 30000 or 50000 make less calls but in all cases it get's stuck at around 150000 or 200000.

```
existing_search_result = supabase.table('vehicles').select('ref_id', count='exact').order('id', desc=False).execute()
existing_items = []
range_step = len(existing_search_result.data)
total_existing_items = existing_search_result.count
print(total_existing_items)
while len(existing_items) < total_existing_items:
    try:
        existing_items += (
            supabase.table(
                'vehicles'
            ).select('ref_id')
            .order('id', desc=False)
            .range(range_start, range_start + range_step)
            .execute()
        ).data
        range_start += range_step
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
    print(range_start, len(existing_items))
    time.sleep(0.30)
```

Error log:

```
    2022-10-23 21:04:14,168:ERROR - The read operation timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 8, in map_exceptions
    yield
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/backends/sync.py", line 26, in read
    return self._sock.recv(max_bytes)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1226, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1101, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 60, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 204, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 253, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 237, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(request)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 90, in handle_request
    return self._connection.handle_request(request)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 102, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 81, in handle_request
    ) = self._receive_response_headers(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 143, in _receive_response_headers
    event = self._receive_event(timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 172, in _receive_event
    data = self._network_stream.read(
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/backends/sync.py", line 26, in read
    return self._sock.recv(max_bytes)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 12, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc)
httpcore.ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/main.py", line 278, in job
    supabase.table(
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/postgrest/_sync/request_builder.py", line 53, in execute
    r = self.session.request(
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 802, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 889, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 917, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 954, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 990, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 204, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/ak4zh/updater/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I create a function to get 1000 item and merge it!
this is my code:

```
def count_data(tb_name: str, field_name: str):
return supabase.table(tb_name).select(field_name, count='exact').execute().count


def get_field_data(tb_name: str, src_field: str, len_record: int, id_field: str = 'id'):
  if len_record <= 1000:
    field_data = supabase.table(tb_name).select(id_field, src_field).order(
        column=id_field).execute().data
  else:
    rnk = int(len_record / 1000)
    field_data = []
    for i in range(rnk):
        min_rg = (i * 1000) + 1
        max_rg = (i + 1) * 1000
        field_data = field_data + supabase.table(tb_name).select(id_field, src_field).order(
            column=id_field).range(min_rg - 1, max_rg).execute().data

    field_data = field_data + supabase.table(tb_name).select(id_field, src_field).order(
        column=id_field).range(max_rg, len_record).execute().data
  return field_data
```

Comment: Not a very big issue perhaps, but the codes in the count_data function should be indented. On the other hand, this function helped me a lot. Could not find any good resources up till now on how to get the count of rows from a big table in supabase.